# How to create a metro style form?

Tags: .net, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

The installation of visual studio 2012 has metro style forms, is there any way of creating applications with similar style in visual studio?

Comment: It doesn't, a "metro style form" doesn't have a close button.  These are just borderless windows with a bunch of code to draw the window and implement window-like behavior.  It isn't exposed as re-usable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create these with WPF, restyling them yourself or with something like [MahApps](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) or [Elysium](http://elysium.codeplex.com/).